Can a storage device completely erase itself while performing the erase?
Let’s say I have a some form of storage media (HDD, SSD, USB, whatever.) But I only have one.
Is it possible for this sole storage device to, without using any other form of storage device, erase (over-write with binary) itself when it’s the storage device whatever erasure program/code is running on?
I think the rather banal problem would be that the program that is running the erase couldn’t keep running after it has partially erased itself.
I suppose it could be possible with a pre-loaded erasure program in RAM, could it not?

No? If your erasing all content on the disk you can't run the program from that disk. Don't worry about the program, what about the OS running it?

@NickSlash even if your hypothesis was true - and it isn't - a program could exist on an encrypted partition ala LUX or Bitlocker, run, then overwrite the header - as the header is still in memory the program could continue to do its work - but when the key is flushed from memory (eg rebooting), the disk is gone.  (And erasing a disk by simply removing a header is fairly standard practice)

Nothing new...except that now it is all digital: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4y9NtHlJvbY

A Linux live CD would allow you to erase the only disk

Yes, of course it can. Programs load into memory - so once they are in memory the disk they are in can be wiped and the program can continue to run.   You just need to ensure the program is small enough to be fully loaded in memory. This is not a hard task if you keep the program small.
Even if it were more complex, nothing to stop you setting up a RAM disk, then copying the program to RAM disk and running it, and deleting the media it came on.
You may have some issues/errors on exit depending on the OS, but the wipe could still be successful.
I tried a quick experiment on my Linux system with dd and did the following:
 cp /usr/bin/dd /tmp
 ls -l /tmp/dd           
 /tmp/dd if=/dev/null bs=102400 > /tmp/dd 
 ls -l /tmp/dd

The output of this was interesting and not as I predicted - The original file was 68120 bytes, and when I attempted to overwrite the command I received an error "Text file busy" but /tmp/dd was truncated and had 0 bytes.
I then tried a more sophisticated trick which also worked and proved it is definitely doable - Creating a loopback filemount, copying the deletion program to it, and then instructing the file to delete the backing device.  This worked and did not immediately error - I used the following commands:
cp /usr/bin/dd /tmp/
/tmp/dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/tmp.file bs=1024 count=1000
mkfs.ext4 /tmp/tmp.file 
mount /tmp/tmp.file /m2
cp /tmp/dd /m2
/m2/dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=100 of=/tmp/tmp.file

Interestingly the command exited and nothing complained.  When I did a dd I saw that /m2 was still mounted - presumably in memory as ls also showed dd.  It even allowed me to create new files on the erased filesystem...   When I unmounted the temporary filesystem and tried to remount it did I was unable to do so because, as expected, the filesystem no longer existed on disk.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

you're overcomplicating it. dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda iflag=fullblock works great. Also, I highly recoomend adding the flag iflag=fullblock , from experience, i've experienced corruption with dd when omitting that flag, and the corruption went away when adding that flag.. so I always use that flag now.

Alternative take on the question - which is still a "Yes" - but only in some cases, there is another interpretation and answer -
If you are referring to wiping the disk the system is on, some higher end devices and drives have a "Secure Erase" function which can be triggered to wipe the disk without relying on software to overwrite each sector - in some cases this can be triggered in the BIOS, in others by a call to the firmware subroutine.  https://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA7-2608ENW.pdf may be useful reading. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000146892/dell-data-wipe and https://www.msi.com/faq/2659 show other vendors offering similar/equivalent functionality.
This answer is, however hardware dependent.  Using encrypted drives and overwriting crypto headers will still work though.

Hmm, interesting indeed. Another good answer.

Programs don't "run on" storage. They run on a CPU, which stores its instructions in registers. What doesn't fit in the registers goes in the cache, and what doesn't fit in the cache goes in active memory. If active memory isn't enough, the program might use "virtual memory", which is where it uses storage to emulate active memory. A program that consists of just "erase everything on this disk" could be encoded in a few dozen bytes. You might be able to get that in just a CPU's registers, and you definitely would be able to fit it in the CPU's cache. There would be no need for active memory, let alone storage.
Also, there is firmware on the disk that likely can't be deleted by the computer.

Yes, absolutely.
The main reason why you need a functioning disk while a program executes is due to virtual memory. Virtual memory allows a program to access memory addresses do not correspond to physical memory. Instead, when those addresses are accessed, a page fault occurs, and the OS transparently loads the intended memory contents (e.g. from disk), updates the page tables which translate virtual memory addresses to physical ones, and returns to the program. This allows an OS to save significant physical memory: a program only loads in the pages it really needs, and can "lazily" load in additional pages into memory as needed.
On operating systems or environments without virtual memory, programs generally have to be loaded fully into memory, or they have to manually implement loading unloaded parts into memory from disk.
Bare-metal programs (such as the BIOS), as well as real-mode operating systems (like DOS) don't usually use virtual memory. Consequently, programs running from those operating systems can typically continue to operate even if the storage medium from which they were loaded is removed or destroyed.
Therefore: one good option to nuke a storage device is to write a barebones "OS" that will be loaded directly to memory by the device's bootloader/BIOS, and which has only the function of erasing the primary disk.

This just moves the problem, from overwriting the active filesystem with zeros, to overwriting the active filesystem with "minimal OS that knows how to erase".  The simplicity of zeroing the disk after the minimal OS loads doesn't remove the problem of overwriting the active system.  (not an insurmountable problem in any case)

@BenVoigt: Indeed, prepare a self-contained initrd ("ram disk") with erase tools, and kexec to boot into that from the current system.  (Or install it as a boot option on the hard drive.)  Bootable HD-erase tools include DBAN (https://dban.org/   Darik's Boot and Nuke.)
